# How do I change the background image on my website?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I want to change it to a png that I already have on the server.
The path for the png is ../assets/ico/paper_fibers.png
The following code does not work:

```
body {
    background-image:url('../assets/ico/paper_fibers.png');
}
```

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong. Do you get an error? Can you show us the site?

Comment: There is no error. www.stribbly.com

Comment: It depends on where your css file is, where do you put it?

Comment: It is a custom.css file that is linked right below another one, which overrules all. The background should look like this http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/paper_fibers.png

Comment: Try ./ or ~/ instead of ../, Well I,m not sure but try this one

Comment: the image path specified in the css file are relative to where the css file resides.

Try placing your css file to same directory level as "assests" and change the url of background image as follow:

background-image:url('./assets/ico/paper_fibers.png');

Comment: Vegetarian Vulture, I don't know what you mean by the ./or path

Answer (score 0):

I went onto your site and just edited it with the browser developer tools, and this seemed to work for me:

```
body {
background-image: url(assets/ico/paper_fibers.png);
}
```

Comment: Where was the css that you edited? bootstrap.css? custom.css?

Comment: Apparently carousel.css